# SQL: Can I convert a string value of a "<" operator into an operator in a where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am storing an operator in a string column for two rows of a table (">", "<=")

I am joining the table with another table and want to make the where clause as dynamic as possible.

I was wondering if it's possible to convert the string value operator into an actual operator for this line of SQL code:

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(dd,Table2.DUE_DT,GETDATE())) > 120
```

VS

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(dd,Table2.DUE_DT,GETDATE())) <= 120
```

The operator will change depending on matching columns in the row. Is it possible to change the operator based of the string value containing the correct operator? If so, how can this be done?

Below are the two rows from Table1

```
NEFL_TYPE   GRGR_ID     NEFL_KEY    NEFL_VALUE  NEFL_COLUMN
"PDRU"      "2600"      "PD"         "RV"        ">"
"PDRU"      "2600"      "RV"         "PD"        "<="
```

This is the snippet of code I use:

```
INNER JOIN
    Table1
ON
    Table2.STATUS = Table1.NEFL_KEY
AND
    Table1.NEFL_TYPE = 'PDRU'
WHERE
    Table1.GRGR_ID = '2600'
AND
    ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, Table2.DUE_DT,GETDATE())) > 120
```

So Table2.STATUS should determine which operator to use in the NEFL_COLUMN

Comment: Are you asking for MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I am asking for SQL Server

Comment: Ok, I've removed the mysql tag then.  Can you also post the definition of your 2 tables and some sample rows for each?  My thought is that you would have to do this using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Pls post all related sql code

Comment: Yes, it's possible (`WHERE (Operator = '<' AND [condition]) OR (Operator = '>=' AND [condition again]) OR ([etcetera])`) . No, you really don't want to if you are in any way interested in performance. Write client code to generate the query dynamically. Alternatively, write T-SQL code to generate the query dynamically, but even that is a pain. There is no generic `EVAL` like mechanism in T-SQL, in any case, or some sort of polymorphic function that can take an operator and imitate it.

Comment: Code and table have been added. Let me know if this suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to do what you want for a general case, not even with dynamic queries or client-side generated queries, as the comparison is per row and performance would be an issue with dynamic queries.

I see 2 ways to solve the particular example case, though:

a) Make 2 separate queries and do a `UNION` on them

```
SELECT...
INNER JOIN
    Table1
ON
    Table2.STATUS = Table1.NEFL_KEY
AND
    Table1.NEFL_TYPE = 'PDRU'
WHERE
    Table1.GRGR_ID = '2600'
AND
    ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, Table2.DUE_DT,GETDATE())) > 120 AND Table1.NEFL_COLUMN = ">"
UNION
SELECT...
INNER JOIN
    Table1
ON
    Table2.STATUS = Table1.NEFL_KEY
AND
    Table1.NEFL_TYPE = 'PDRU'
WHERE
    Table1.GRGR_ID = '2600'
AND
    ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, Table2.DUE_DT,GETDATE())) <= 120 AND Table1.NEFL_COLUMN = "<="
```

b) Use 2 range columns instead of an "operator" column

```
NEFL_TYPE   GRGR_ID     NEFL_KEY    NEFL_VALUE  NEFL_COLUMN   START    END
"PDRU"      "2600"      "PD"         "RV"        ">"           121    9999
"PDRU"      "2600"      "RV"         "PD"        "<="           0      120
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
INNER JOIN
    Table1
ON
    Table2.STATUS = Table1.NEFL_KEY
AND
    Table1.NEFL_TYPE = 'PDRU'
WHERE
    Table1.GRGR_ID = '2600'
AND
    ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, Table2.DUE_DT,GETDATE())) BETWEEN Table1.START AND Table1.END
```

But none of them are as clean or elegant as I think you would like